# Li of submenu in navigation is not displaying in line

Tags: navigation, html-lists, inline

I want to make a li of submenu displaying horizontal. Dont know whats wrong ,i thought everythink is OK but the blocks is vertical.

LI should be 3-4pieces in first line (no more space), then 3-4 in the next line. SOmething like this:[result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYtUP.jpg)

Code here^: https://jsfiddle.net/83hd75uq/4/
CSS:

```
#navigation{
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
width: 1000px;
height: 70px;
background: pink;
margin: auto;
}
#navigation  nav{
font-size: 37px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
width: 930px;

}
#navigation  nav > ul{

list-style-type: none;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;

}
#navigation  nav > ul > li{
    position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
}
#navigation  nav > ul > li > a{
padding: 12px;
float: left;
color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
}
#navigation  nav > ul > li > a:hover{
color: white;
opacity: 0.9;
}

#navigation    li:hover > ul {display: inline-block; z-index: 1;}
#navigation    li > ul{
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
top: 100%;
right: -25%;
background: pink;
}
#navigation  nav > ul > li > ul > li{
 display: inline-block;position: relative; margin: 0 auto; height: 100%;
}
#navigation  nav > ul > li > ul > li p{
    margin: 3px auto;

}
#navigation  nav > ul > li > ul > li a{
float: left; margin: 0 7px;
}
.submenubonbonlink:hover div.navbonbon {
    background :  red!important;  background-size: 200px 200px!important; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.navcategorysimages {width: 200px; height: 200px; display: inline-block;float: left;}
.navbonbon{ background :white!important;  background-size: 200px 200px!important; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div  id="navigation" >
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="/">sometext</a> </li> 
<li><a href="/">sometext</a>
         <ul>

            <li ><a  href="/" class="submenubonbonlink"> <div class="navbonbon navcategorysimages"></div><p>sometext</p></a></li >
            <li ><a  href="/" class="submenubonbonlink"> <div class="navbonbon navcategorysimages"></div><p>sometext</p></a></li >
             <li ><a  href="/" class="submenubonbonlink"> <div class="navbonbon navcategorysimages"></div><p>sometext</p></a></li >
         </ul> 
      </li>
<li><a href="/">sometext</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>
```